# A map $f:([a,b], |\cdot|) \to ([c,d], |\cdot|)$ is an isometry if and only if $d-c = b-a$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I was asked to prove the following problem:
A map $f:([a,b], |\cdot|) \to ([c,d], |\cdot|)$ is an isometry if and only if $d-c = b-a$.

But I think this is not correct, specifically the sufficient part. Can anyone please suggest the correct version of the question and a hint to solve it?

Comment: Probably it should say that *there exists* such an isometry if and only if $d-c=b-a$. You are correct that $d-c=b-a$ is not sufficient for an arbitrary function to be an isometry!

Comment: @MattPressland I think you are correct. Can you suggest me some way to prove the necessity part in that case?

Comment: Actually I wasn't correct - the suggestion in Chellapillai is much better. (I forgot that the usual definition of isometry doesn't require invertibility, unlike most "iso" things.) Probably the easiest thing is a contradiction; if the widths of the intervals are different, then the endpoints of one interval are further apart than any pair of points of the other interval, which will give you a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, $f:[0,1]\to[0,2]$ defined by $f(x)=x$ is an isometry but $1\neq 2$. So the correct formulation will be: There exists a surjective isometry  $f:[a,b]\to[c,d]$ iff $b-a=d-c$

Comment: Can you suggest me some way to prove the necessity part in that case?

Comment: $f$ surjective implies that, $f(x_0)=c,f(y_0)=d$. Hence $d-c=|f(x_0)-f(y_0)|=|x_0-y_0|\leq b-a$. Simlary, since $f^{-1}$ is an isomerty, $b-a\leq d-c$.  Hence $d-c=b-a$

Answer (score 1):

The map $f(x)=x^2$, from $([0,1],|\cdot|)$ to $([0,1],|\cdot|)$ is not an isometry, despite the fact that $1-0=1-0$.

Answer (score 0):

The correct definition of an isometry under the $|\cdot |$ metric is $|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in [a,b]$.

Comment: I'm not sure this actually addresses the question; I think the sentence in the first line is meant to be a problem, not a definition.

Comment: @MattPressland: Hopefully OP will actually say what his definition of isometry is for the problem at hand.